# Create keyboard shortcuts for certain symbols (like logical operators)

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, shortcuts, text-processing

(using Ubuntu 12.04)

currently I'm dealing a lot with logic (not for computer science, though), so my idea was to create specific shortcuts on my keyboard for easy typing.

my idea is to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> and then a specific key.

e.g.

when I type
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>
in a text editor or chat-program, or whatever, I want it to type the logical operator for "or": ∨

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>^</kbd>  I want it to become the logical operator "and": ∧

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>  I want it to become ≠

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>  I want it to become ∃

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>  I want it to become the modal operator for "possible": ◊

and so on, and so on. You get the idea.

Instructions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The closest I have come to this so far is to use (on lubuntu 14.04.1) `<ctrl><shift>U` then type the code say 00ac for ¬ which I found by using the character map.
This is pretty quick way of doing it, if you know the code and remember each one. If I find another way I will update.